# Does an element cover bandwidth when it's display is none

Tags: html, iframe, bandwidth

When an element has its display property set as none, does it cover any bandwidth? For example, I have an iframed video whose display is none. Does it occupy user bandwidth?

Comment: This element is still part of the DOM, just not rendered. I would presume that it won't use any, unless it is one of those players that start pre-downloading the video, and even then I am just guessing. Why don't you inspect your Network traffic and see it for yourself?

Comment: @HanletEscaño thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it does. Having an elements display set to none in css doesn't make any difference in bandwidth usage. If you want to save bandwidth, make the video load only if it's going to be played.

Comment: Look at this JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gschwu9w/. Let me know if it is using any bandwith. Youtube player tends to not stream anything until the user clicks on the play button, or the initial loading image.

Comment: If it's a youtube video, it does not use any bandwidth after the initial load unless the user starts the playback. I assumed it's a playing video when answering the question.

Comment: I see what you mean, the video is already playing and then the element is hidden. It would indeed use bandwith.

Comment: You could completely remove the video if it's not going to be used anymore on the page, rather than hiding it.